# `this` is undefined when calling method from another context

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, constructor, scope

This is my first time creating OOP for JS. I followed some tutorials but I can't wrap my head around this issue. I know the problem, but i dont know the solution

```
function NewApp(name){
    this.name = name;
    this.currentPage = 1;
    this.customObjectWithMethods = //init with options and so on
}

NewApp.prototype.logic = function(){
// Note 1.  
    var app = this
    //Note 3.
    this.customObjectWithMethods.method{
        if(app.currentpage < 3)
            // Note 2.  
            app.navigate(app.logic)
    }
}

NewApp.prototype.navigate = function(sender){
    var app = this;
    this.customObjectWithMethods.method{
        app.currentpage++;
        this.method(function() {
            return app.currentPage === 2;
        }, sender(), this.terminate);
    } 
}
```

- **Note 1:** I need to create a reference because after that, `this` doesn't
  work anymore to refer to the current object.
- **Note 2:**  After the check I want to do some logic in another method and repeat the current function, but when the function runs again it breaks on the method (`this.customObjectWithMethods`) because `this` doesn't exists.
- **Note 3:** This is where it breaks because "this" works the first time not the second time.

It gets very complicated like this with the `this`-keyword, which makes me think that my design may be flawed.

Is there any solution for this problem, or should I refactor it ?

Comment: You haven't made a mistake. That is just the way the "this" keyword works in JS. "this" does not refer to the containing object. It is determined by how the function is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surely it will become complicated, `this`keyword doesn't always refer to the main object but to the scope where it is used, take a look at [**Scope and this in JavaScript**](http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2012/04/javascript-variable-scope-this/) for further information.

This is your way to go, make a variable that contains your constructor and add these two methods to this variable, after that you can call your functions:

```
var newApp = function newApp(name){
    this.name = name;
    this.currentPage = 1;

    //Make a reference to your object here
    var THIS = this;

    this.logic = function(){ 
        var sender = this;

        THIS.customObjectWithMethods.method = function(){
            if(THIS.currentpage < 3) 
                THIS.navigate(sender);
        }
    }

    this.navigate = function(sender){
        this.customObjectWithMethods.method = function(){
            THIS.currentpage++;
            this.method(function() {
                return THIS.currentPage === 2;
            }, sender(), this.terminate);
        } 
    }    

}
```

And this is how to use your constructor and its methods:

```
var app = newApp("Test");

//Call the first method
app.customObjectWithMethods();

//Thenn call the second one
app.logic();
```

Comment: I removed the functions all out of the prototype but I am still getting the same error at note 3. After the function is called (sender) it doesnt know the object... "this"

Comment: In the `//Note 3.` Are you trying to call the `customObjectWithMethods` function here?

Comment: yeah the first time it works... it goes to navigate... that does some logic and fires the sender function again but now the this doesnt work anymore there is no reference to the object that has this.customobjectwithmethods

Comment: try to attach your functions to prototype ;)

Comment: @MichaelAngelo take a look at the functions in my EDIT, always refer to the app with `THIS`.

Comment: @chsdk that worked :) it looks very hacky... is this how it supposed to be :) ?

Comment: Yes indeed it is, you can use prototype here but this is much better approach, because as you can see [in this link](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/three-javascript-anti-patterns-and-how-to-avoid-them.html) extending objects is an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Some syntax errors & style issues - here is a short correction

```
var myFunction = function(){
    //code here
};

var mySecondFunction = function(){
    //code here
};

function NewApp(name){
this.name = name;
this.currentPage = 1;
this.customObjectWithMethods = function(){}; //empty function so calling doesnt resolve in error

}

NewApp.prototype.logic = function(){

   this.customObjectWithMethods.method = mySecondFunction.bind(this);
}

NewApp.prototype.navigate = function(sender){

    this.customObjectWithMethods.method = myFunction.bind(this);

}
```

I have moved the 2 functions outside of the constructor Function so they dont get recreated every time you call the constructor functions.

with _.bind(this) the "this"-reference gets passed into the scope of your functions (i think this is more pretty than creating another var).

with

```
var reff = new NewApp('namename');
```

you can get started calling your functions now:

```
ref.logic();
```

maybe this approach works for you?

Comment: i am calling the function of the same object so i dont know how this would work as this solution but didnt know the .bind option.. The problem occurs when you re-call the same function than then "this" doesnt work anymore how can you still refer to the object

Comment: this example should work. You pass the scope of your constructor function into your "helper"-functions. Maybe give some more code to prove your point? give an example of how you call it